# how to create $http post service using defer and promise in angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, node.js

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []);
myAppModule.controller('mainController', function($scope, userService) {
    $scope.addUser = function() {
        var email = $scope.user.email;
        var password = $scope.user.password;
        userService.addFriend(email, password).then(function() {
            console.log( 'errorMessage' );
        });
        $scope.user.email = '';
        $scope.user.password = '';
    }
});
app.service('userService', function($http, $q) {
    var deffered = $q.defer();
});
```

This is my incomplete code please correct it. Please make it correct.

Comment: what error are you getting ?

Comment: no i am not getting any error i just wanted to know the structure of services and controller that how the data flows using promises and defer

Answer (score 2):

See below the comments how data flows between controller and service ..

```
var myAppModule = angular.module('myApp', []);
// Your controller starts here 
     myAppModule.controller('mainController', function($scope,userService){
        $scope.addUser = function(){
         var email = $scope.user.email;
         var password = $scope.user.password;
         // Call the Service API which is returns a PROMISE
         userService.addFriend(email, password).then(function(response){
         // you will receive data here .. 
         // do what you want to do with data on success

         }, function(error){ // here error comes ...});
         $scope.user.email = '';
         $scope.user.password = '';
       }
  });

  // your service starts here 

  app.service('userService', function($http){
    // you dont require defer $q
    // var deffered = $q.defer();
    // this function returns $http promise...

    this.addFriend = function(email, password){

        return $http({
            url : "enter url here",
            data : JSON.stringify({email: email, password : password}),
            method : "GET" // can be GET or POST based on your API
          });

    };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the required method `addFriend` in `userService`, heres an example

```
myAppModule.service('userService', function($http, $q){
      this.addFriend = function (email, password) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            var promise = $http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: <<Url>>,
                data: { 
                    email : email, 
                    password : password
                }
            }).success(function (data) {
                deferred.resolve(data);
            }).error(function (data, status) {
                deferred.reject(data);
            });
            return promise;
     }
});
```

Comment: shouldn't it return `return deferred.promise;` instead of `$http` promise .. ?

Comment: can u just define its controller to receive that service

Comment: @user3565243, you can use the controller defined in your question